# How can I 'align' python, pip and environments? I'm trying to install certbot on ubuntu VPS

Tags: python, python3, pip

Ubuntu 20.04 **VPS** on hostinger

```
$ whereis python  
python: /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python3.8 /usr/bin/python3.9 /usr/bin/python3.8-config /usr/lib/python2.7 /usr/lib/python3.8 /usr/lib/python3.9 /etc/python2.7 /etc/python3.8 /etc/python3.9 /usr/local/lib/python2.7 /usr/local/lib/python3.8 /usr/local/lib/python3.9 /usr/include/python3.8 /usr/share/python /opt/certbot/bin/python  
  
$ whereis pip  
pip: /usr/local/bin/pip /usr/local/bin/pip3.9 /usr/local/bin/pip3.8 /usr/share/man/man1/pip.1.gz
```

Are multiple instances of 3 different versions of python installed on my server?
I seem to be having trouble with pip and pip3. I'm trying to do this and getting nothing but errors:
https://certbot.eff.org/instructions?ws=other&os=pip

```
$ sudo python3 -m venv /opt/certbot/  
Command '['/opt/certbot/bin/python3', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

but the folder /opt/certbot was created with sub directories. The folder /opt/certbot/bin/ was created but /opt/certbot/bin/pip was not created.

```
$ sudo /opt/certbot/bin/pip install --upgrade pip  
/opt/certbot/bin/pip: command not found
```

How can I make this command work?

```
sudo /opt/certbot/bin/pip install --upgrade pip
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a new venv I needed to install python3-venv from apt

`sudo apt install python3-venv`

When i ran `python3 -m venv [venv dir]`

It produced this error

```
The virtual environment was not created successfully because ensurepip is not
available.  On Debian/Ubuntu systems, you need to install the python3-venv
package using the following command.

    apt install python3.10-venv

You may need to use sudo with that command.  After installing the python3-venv
package, recreate your virtual environment.

Failing command: ['/home/wsl2/user_venv/bin/python3', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']
```

The more general package python3-venv is probably a better package to install than the seguested `python3.10-venv`

Answer (score 0):

> Are multiple instances of 3 different versions of python installed on
> my server?

Yes,

Ubuntu comes with Python 3   but some applications require Python 2 or some other version of python 3.x or 2.x.

PIP is a soft link for a particular installer. pip3 is an updated version of pip which is used basically for python 3+

Did you forget to run this ?

```
sudo apt install python3 python3-venv libaugeas0
```